# Steam API Retrieve Personal Game Data

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm working on an application that lets you view your csgo match history and watch specified matches directly from the app. Right now I have it working for competitive matches. The way I currently have it working is I request matches as if I were in the game, through the game coordinator, and it works great. The only downside is that I don't get all the games, for example wingman games. I recently found that a user can go to their profile page, into games, then click on personal game data for some games, and see all their match history. For csgo it includes matchmaking, competitive, wingman, operations, casual, etc. So I'm wondering if there is a way to get this information through web api or any other api?

Answer (score 2):

Steam API would be the best way, access into other matches is harder to get, but not impossible, I worked on one for Terraria, giving data access and I can't find the code but youtube does help :)

Comment: Steams own API would be the best

Comment: I've looked through Steam's web api and it has ways to get player statistics like achievements and recent games played, but I couldn't find anything relating to personal game data. If you could be more specific, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Well yeah sure, the web api has many functions to be used with the web key. I'm looking for a function to get the matches a person has played. For example this [link](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats) from Steam's web api documentation shows functions for retrieving stats on a user. GetUserStatsForGame gives lots of good information like total kills, deaths, etc. I'm looking for a function, that would possibly be called GetPersonalGameData, that gets the recent matches of a player. Do you know of any such function or possibly another api that can do this?

Comment: In an older Steam API I used GetGameDataPersonal but I can't seem to see it in the new API

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to the old api for this function?

Comment: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetGameDataPersonal/32_3bc  -found this in an old document from the project hope this works

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't list a function for getting recent matches, just the usual functions for achievements and recently played games. I guess Valve still hasn't released any api for personal game data yet.

Comment: @OxtersWyzgowski have you found a way to do it? I wan't to check how many competitive wins the user has.